# Emoji view in iOS chat application using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, quickblox, emoji

I am working on chat application, Where I need to show Emoji view on button selection. So I can select and send emoji within the text message. This functionality is already inside Messenger application. I know there is button already in keyboard but I want to add button outside keyboard. Please let me know if there is any resource available to get it done quickly.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can array of Emoji.

```
let emojiRanges = [
    0x1F601...0x1F64F, // emoticons
    0x1F30D...0x1F567, // Other additional symbols
    0x1F680...0x1F6C0, // Transport and map symbols
    0x1F681...0x1F6C5 //Additional transport and map symbols
]

var emojis: [String] = []

       for range in emojiRanges {
        for i in range {
            let c = String(describing: UnicodeScalar(i)!)
            emojis.append(c)
        }
    }
```